# put label over textfield on hover change the location css

Tags: html, css

I need to design this text field initially on page load it will be like below image
[image]

on hover the label will move up and color will change
[image]

any solution link for the same.

Thanks

Comment: What HTML are you starting with, when you tried to implement this how far did you get? You say that you "*need to design this text field...*," so what have you done so far? What went wrong?

Comment: This is usually called "floating labels" (and you can read here, https://medium.com/simple-human/floating-labels-are-a-bad-idea-82edb64220f6 or here, https://adamsilver.io/blog/8-reasons-float-labels-are-problematic-and-what-to-do-instead/, why they are a rather bad idea to begin with :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of `~` and `:placeholder-shown` css selectors to achieve this.

Here is an example :

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

.floating-label-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.floating-label {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 15px;
  top: 11px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.floating-input {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.floating-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #3D85D8;
}

.floating-input:focus~.floating-label {
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #3D85D8;
}

.floating-input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  color: #3D85D8;
  border: 1px solid #3D85D8;
}

.floating-input:not(:placeholder-shown)~.floating-label {
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #3D85D8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="floating-label-content">
    <input class="floating-input" type="text" placeholder=" ">
    <label class="floating-label">Your Name</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example and adapt it for your use:
https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/